# Fullcalendar events on 100% width on a resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I am having some trouble with the full calendar plugin.
I have to resources: Resource One and Resource Two. Both are employees for my company. So the purple background is a schedule for Resource one.

The first problem with the schdule was that it left a tiny empty space on the right side of it so you can select a new event. I wanted it on 100% width. As you can see, the purple background is 100% for a resource, that works fine.

But if I drop an event (it has to be a drop, not select or anything else possible, only drop), the event starts at the half of the resource and overlaps the other resource

Here is a picture of what is going on:

[image: As you can see, the event starts at the half of resource one]

My code for the 100% width of the schedule and events:

```
    eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
        schedule = $('.highlighting');
        width = $('.fc-widget-content').width();
        width = width + 'px';
        $(element).css('width',width);
        $(schedule).css('opacity', '0.4');          
    },
```

Does any one have an idea how I could solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle please?

Comment: I am not sure if it is what you were looking for.. But this is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YDa35/